# T-SQL select multiple information from leading rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

My table looks like this

```
    [NUM_STD],[NUM_PERS],[NUM_LIG],[NUM_REP],[NUM_ART],  [CODE_OBS],[INF_COMP]

    31210      385        0100      001       5010244203  NULL       NULL
    31210      385        0200      001       0000000000  NULL       430 DTE 29500
    31210      385        0300      001       5001837123  RNV        NULL
    31210      385        0400      002       5010452955  NULL       NULL
    31210      385        0500      003       5000660009  NULL       NULL
    31210      385        0600      004       5003057046  NULL       NULL
    31210      385        0700      005       7420998835  NULL       NULL
    31210      385        0800      005       0000000000  NULL       D=60 MM
    31210      385        0900      006       5001854688  RNV        NULL
    31210      385        1000      007       5001866891  RNV        NULL
    31210      385        1100      007       0000000000  NULL       "FULL SERVICE"
    31210      385        1200      007       0000000000  RLT        D30
```

What I want to have is an output like this:

```
    [NUM_STD],[NUM_PERS],[NUM_REP],[NUM_ART],[COD_OBS],[INF_COMP]

    31210      385        001         5010244203  NULL       430 DTE 29500
    31210      385        001         5001837123  RNV        NULL
    31210      385        002         5010452955  NULL       NULL
    31210      385        003         5000660009  NULL       NULL
    31210      385        004         5003057046  NULL       NULL
    31210      385        005         7420998835  NULL       D=60 MM
    31210      385        006         5001854688  RNV        NULL
    31210      385        007         5001866891  RNV        "FULL SERVICE", RLT, D30
```

I've tried to use LEAD but the result was not the one above.

Please help me with this one

Comment: On what logi you expect the output? please provide the query you are using to get the output you mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean by logi? I just need a query for the output above

Comment: I meant logic. currently I don't understand how you get the current output. if you post your query we can understand the logic for result.

Comment: I don't have one.
The logic is whenever NUM_STD, NUM_PERS, NUM_REP are equal, take the value from NUM_ART which is not 0000000000, COD_OBS, INF_COMP and COD_OBS plus INF_COMP from the rows with NUM_ART = 0000000000

Comment: It's still unclear to me. Why 5010244203  and 5001837123  don't have the same INF_COMP if it's meant to be taken from row with NUM_ART = 0000000000 ?

Comment: @orhtej2, I think his logic is only look to the next row with NUM_ART=00000. so 5001837123 prints as is, because there is no more orws for that category.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the answer. At least it works on the provided sample data.

My only assumption is NUM_LIG is the order of the records.

```
create table #t
(
NUM_STD int,
NUM_PERS int,
NUM_LIG varchar(10),
NUM_REP varchar(5),
NUM_ART varchar(20),
CODE_OBS varchar(5) NULL,
INF_COMP varchar(20) NULL
)
insert into #t values
(31210, 385, '0100', '001' ,'5010244203',  NULL , NULL            ),
(31210, 385, '0200', '001' ,'0000000000',  NULL , '430 DTE 29500' ),
(31210, 385, '0300', '001' ,'5001837123',  'RNV',   NULL          ),
(31210, 385, '0400', '002' ,'5010452955',  NULL , NULL            ),
(31210, 385, '0500', '003' ,'5000660009',  NULL , NULL            ),
(31210, 385, '0600', '004' ,'5003057046',  NULL , NULL            ),
(31210, 385, '0700', '005' ,'7420998835',  NULL , NULL            ),
(31210, 385, '0800', '005' ,'0000000000',  NULL , 'D=60 MM'       ),
(31210, 385, '0900', '006' ,'5001854688',  'RNV',   NULL          ),
(31210, 385, '1000', '007' ,'5001866891',  'RNV',   NULL          ),
(31210, 385, '1100', '007' ,'0000000000',  NULL , '"FULL SERVICE"'),
(31210, 385, '1200', '007' ,'0000000000',  'RLT',   'D30'         )


;with ct as (
    select NUM_STD, NUM_PERS, NUM_REP, NUM_ART, 
    isnull(lead(CODE_OBS) over 
        (partition by NUM_STD, NUM_PERS, NUM_REP order by NUM_LIG), CODE_OBS) AS L_CODE_OBS,
    isnull(lead(INF_COMP) over 
        (partition by NUM_STD, NUM_PERS, NUM_REP order by NUM_LIG), INF_COMP) AS L_INF_COMP
    from #t
)
select *
from ct
where NUM_ART <> '0000000000'
```

Comment: It is not showing the correct result, for example, the last row

Comment: oh, looks like there should be a concatenation. I'll update my answer

Comment: perhaps, but that should be concatenated across two columns when there are multiple "0.." lines follow by

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012 and up the following should in theory work.

```
DECLARE @SampleData TABLE
(
    NUM_STD     INT,
    NUM_PERS    INT,
    NUM_LIG     VARCHAR(10),
    NUM_REP     VARCHAR(5),
    NUM_ART     VARCHAR(20),
    CODE_OBS    VARCHAR(5) NULL,
    INF_COMP    VARCHAR(20) NULL
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData 
VALUES
(31210, 385, '0100', '001' ,'5010244203',  NULL , NULL            ),
(31210, 385, '0200', '001' ,'0000000000',  NULL , '430 DTE 29500' ),
(31210, 385, '0300', '001' ,'5001837123',  'RNV',   NULL          ),
(31210, 385, '0400', '002' ,'5010452955',  NULL , NULL            ),
(31210, 385, '0500', '003' ,'5000660009',  NULL , NULL            ),
(31210, 385, '0600', '004' ,'5003057046',  NULL , NULL            ),
(31210, 385, '0700', '005' ,'7420998835',  NULL , NULL            ),
(31210, 385, '0800', '005' ,'0000000000',  NULL , 'D=60 MM'       ),
(31210, 385, '0900', '006' ,'5001854688',  'RNV',   NULL          ),
(31210, 385, '1000', '007' ,'5001866891',  'RNV',   NULL          ),
(31210, 385, '1100', '007' ,'0000000000',  NULL , '"FULL SERVICE"'),
(31210, 385, '1200', '007' ,'0000000000',  'RLT',   'D30'         );


;WITH CTE_SampleData
AS
(
    SELECT   NUM_STD    
            ,NUM_PERS
            ,NUM_LIG    
            ,NUM_REP    
            ,NUM_ART    
            ,CODE_OBS
            ,INF_COMP
            -- Mark all records where NUM_ART is not zero, this will be used to help generate a grouping ID
            ,(
                CASE 
                    WHEN NUM_ART = '0000000000' THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                 END 
             ) AS ZeroLine 
    FROM    @SampleData
), CTE_SampleDataWithGroupID
AS
(
    SELECT   NUM_STD    
            ,NUM_PERS
            ,NUM_LIG    
            ,NUM_REP    
            ,NUM_ART    
            ,CODE_OBS
            ,INF_COMP
            -- Create running total on ZeroLine column. This will effectively create a grouping id that will allow us to group all zero line records with preceding record.
            ,SUM(ZeroLine) OVER (ORDER BY NUM_STD, NUM_PERS,NUM_REP, NUM_LIG) AS GroupID
            -- Combine information from CODE_OBS and INF_COMP columns where applicable into the new Info column.
            ,IIF(NUM_ART = '0000000000', COALESCE(CODE_OBS + ', ' + INF_COMP, INF_COMP), NULL) AS Info
    FROM    CTE_SampleData
)
SELECT  [SD].GroupID
        ,MAX([SD].NUM_STD) AS NUM_STD
        ,MAX([SD].NUM_PERS) AS NUM_PERS
        ,MAX([SD].NUM_REP) AS NUM_REP
        ,MAX([SD].NUM_ART) AS NUM_ART
        ,MAX([SD].CODE_OBS) AS CODE_OBS
        -- Create a comma delimited string combining all Info for the group into a single record.
        ,STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Info
                    FROM CTE_SampleDataWithGroupID
                    WHERE GroupID = [SD].GroupID
                    FOR XML PATH ('')
                )
          , 1, 1, '')  AS INF_COMP
FROM    CTE_SampleDataWithGroupID [SD]
GROUP BY    [SD].GroupID
```